# Replacing the handlebar grips with ergonomic ones?

Tags: handlebars, ergonomics, grips

I had bought this set a while back and I eventually managed to replace them the other day, but... It didn't work! The length of the bar is too short to reach the end of the new grips, i don't know where to buy a metal bar, and even if I do, it'll cost a lot to get them and have them cut in two small pieces as attachments to these grips. I noticed this thread reel is tight enough if I squeeze into the vertical attachment from one side and the main bar from the other, but I'm not sure if it's strong enough. Is there any other way I can get around with this?

[image: too long!]

[image: reel]

[image: done!]

Comment: You have four choices:  Buy longer handlebar, buy shorter grips, live with them the way they are, cut them shorter.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is a little hard to tell from your photos, but do you have grip shifters?

For setups with grip shifters, the grips are generally much shorter / narrower, as part of the "grip surface" is the shifter itself.

If you do indeed have grip shifters, you can do as ojs suggested & move the shifters / brakes in towards the stem, or, you could return the grips you purchased & get something sized properly to work with grip shifters.

Notice the difference in width of these grips:

[image: Grips]
The ones on the left are made to work with trigger shifters, while the  ones on the right are made to work with grip shifters. For reference, some examples of grips meant for use with grip shifters can be found [here](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=sr_nr_p_n_feature_keywords_6?fst=as%3Aoff&rh=n%3A3375251%2Cn%3A%213375301%2Cn%3A706814011%2Cn%3A3403201%2Cn%3A3404731%2Cn%3A6389387011%2Cn%3A3494261%2Cp_n_feature_keywords_browse-bin%3A4594458011&bbn=3494261&ie=UTF8&qid=1438357213&rnid=2765729011).

(Edit: I'd avoid the thread spool idea. Go over an unexpected bump while resting on the bar ends & they pop off because they were secured with a thread spool... loose control & crash!!)

Comment: If you have grip shifts, you should use the ones for grip shipfts. the shifting motion won't feel right and the brakes won't be as accessible if you move them inboard and use the regular version. Plus, if you're spending enough money to go for Ergon grips, may as well do it right.

Comment: Good point, I didn't notice the grip shifters.

Answer (score 4):

You can move the brake and shift levers inward. They are tightened around the handlebar with hex bolts or screws, you can loosen these and move the parts around. If the result feels too narrow, you can change to a wider handlebar.

Edit: See the other answer for solution with grip shifters.

Comment: I tried that, but it's still too short to hold everything and have extra for the vertical attachments.

Comment: Then it's time to get a longer handlebar. They aren't that expensive.